# Ocaml - How can I convert value of int variable to string?

Tags: ocaml

I want to make string "t1", "t2","t3", ...so on.

so I did like this
let i =0;...
(something) -> let z = "t" ^ string_of_int (i+1)

my intention is every time that program enters (something), i increases.
because I have to make new string when program enters (something).

but it had syntax error
What should I do?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "it didn't work" mean? In what way doesn't it work? Do you get an error? If yes, what is the error you are getting? Don't you get the result you are expecting? If yes, what is the resulting you are expecting (and why), what is the result you are getting, and in what way do they differ? Does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior? If yes, what is the behavior you are expecting (and why), what is the behavior you are observing, and in what way do they differ? Can you provide a precise specification of what it is that you want to happen, …

Comment: … including any and all corner cases, special cases, edge cases, and exceptions? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the edge cases?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to embed an integer as part of a string, use `Printf.sprintf`:

```
let make_string i =
  Printf.sprintf "t%d" i
```

You'll have to take care of tht part that generates increasing numbers with something else, like a `for` loop.